# Exporting Imagecollection in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

When we export the "SM" Imagecollection (line 517), Goggle Earth Engine gets stuck, whether it is exported as Asset or to Google Drive.

Has anything similar happened to anyone who has been able to solve it?

The repository link: https://github.com/QianqianHan96/GSSM1km/blob/main/GSSM1km%20generation.

```
var MERIT = ee.Image("MERIT/Hydro/v1_0_1"),
    MOD13A2 = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2"),
    table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/qianrswaterr/globalBoundary/World_Continents"),
    ERA5Land = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5_LAND/HOURLY"),
    imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("users/qianrswaterr/WTD"),
    DTB = ee.Image("users/qianrswaterr/predictors/BDTICM_M_1km_ll"),
    trainTest = ee.FeatureCollection("users/qianrswaterr/GlobalSSM2022/trainTestFinal2022-0509coor"),
    valiEva = ee.FeatureCollection("users/qianrswaterr/GlobalSSM2022/valiEvaFinal2022-0509coor"),
    NLsamples = ee.FeatureCollection("users/qianrswaterr/NLsamples/trainTestNL2022-0509coor"),
    TIele = ee.Image("users/qianrswaterr/GlobalSSM/TIele1000resample0709");


var WTD = imageCollection.mosaic().reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000).rename('WTD'); 
DTB = DTB.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000).rename('DTB')
var EuropeBoundary=table.filterMetadata("CONTINENT","equals","Europe");
///////////////NDVI & EVI
var modis = MOD13A2
var oeel=require('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
var firstYear = 2019
var firstDaymodis = ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear).subtract(1)).cat('-12-13');
var lastDaymodis = ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear).add(1)).cat('-01-18');
// 26 images in the current year
modis=modis.filterDate(firstDaymodis,lastDaymodis).select(["NDVI","EVI"]);
print("originalMODIS",modis);
Map.addLayer(modis.select(["NDVI","EVI"]),{},"original NDVI&EVI")
// SG filter
var s=oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(modis,
        ee.Filter.maxDifference(1000*3600*24*48, 'system:time_start', null, 'system:time_start'),
        function(infromedImage,estimationImage){
          return ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(infromedImage.get('system:time_start'))
            .subtract(ee.Number(estimationImage.get('system:time_start'))));},
        3,["NDVI","EVI"],modis);
//print("SG NDVI & EVI in the current year and 12/19(or 12/18) of the previous year, 1/17 of the next year)",s)

///////////////////////////Linear interpolation
////24 images, filter 12/19(or 12/18) and 1/17 which have masked values
s=ee.ImageCollection(s.toList(26).slice(1,25)).select(["d_0_NDVI","d_0_EVI"])
  .map(function(img){
    return img//.unmask(0)
  })
//print('SG NDVI & EVI only in the current year',s)
//Map.addLayer(s.select(["d_0_NDVI","d_0_EVI"]),{},'SG NDVI&EVI')
// Yr start date 
var ddStart = ee.Number(s.aggregate_min('system:time_start'));
// Yr end date
var ddEnd =  ee.Number(s.aggregate_max('system:time_start'));
// DD list
var ddList = ee.List.sequence(ddStart, ddEnd, (24*60*60*1000));
// DD list to img collection  
var ddCll = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
                    ddList.map(function (tuple){return ee.Image.constant(tuple).toInt64()
                              .set('system:time_start',ee.Number(tuple))
                              .select(['constant'],['time']);
                            })
);
// Original NDVI copier
function copyValue (img){
 var time = img.metadata('system:time_start');
 function mask (val){
   var timeOrig = val.metadata('system:time_start');
   var masked = timeOrig.eq(time);
   return val.mask(masked);
 }
 var ndviCll = s.map(mask);
 return img.addBands(ndviCll.max()); 
}
var filledDate = ddCll.map(copyValue);
//print('filledDate',filledDate)

var day = (24*60*60*1000);
var timeDelta = (16*day);
// when 12/19, it is 13 days
// when 12/18, it is 14 days
var timeDelta1= (13*day);
// Create a list of original calculated dates
var startDayList = s.toList(24).map(function(ele){
  ele=ee.Image(ele)
  return ele.get("system:time_start")
}).slice(0,23)
// convert it in an image collection
function toImage(tuple){
  return ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(tuple)).set('system:time_start',tuple);
}
var imgCll = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(startDayList.map(toImage));

///////////////*******************************//////////////////////
/////////////The function to interpolate EVI
function NDVIinterpolator(img){
  img=ee.Image(img)
  // get the first day of the subsample 
  var begin = ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'));
  // get the end day of the subsample
  //var end = begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta));
  var difference = ee.String(ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'))).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).slice(5).compareTo("12-18").neq(0)
                   .and(ee.String(ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'))).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).slice(5).compareTo("12-19").neq(0))
  var end = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
            begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta)),
            begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta1))
  )
  //convert to an image
  var minDD = ee.Image(filledDate.filterDate(begin).first()); 
  var maxDD = ee.Image(filledDate.filterDate(end).first());
  
  //calculate the coefficent
  var angularCoeff = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
                     (maxDD.select('d_0_NDVI').subtract(minDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))).divide(timeDelta),
                     (maxDD.select('d_0_NDVI').subtract(minDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))).divide(timeDelta1)
  )
  var q = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
          ((maxDD.select('time').multiply(minDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))).subtract(minDD.select('time').multiply(maxDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))))
          .divide(timeDelta),
          ((maxDD.select('time').multiply(minDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))).subtract(minDD.select('time').multiply(maxDD.select('d_0_NDVI'))))
          .divide(timeDelta1)
  )
  //refilter the out collection
  var mnth = filledDate.filterDate(begin,end);
  
  // interpolate the values
  function ndviInterpolator(img){
    var NDVI = (img.select('time').multiply(angularCoeff)).add(q);
    var result = img.select('d_0_NDVI').unmask(NDVI);
    return result;
  }
  var filledMth = mnth.map(ndviInterpolator);
  return filledMth.cast({"d_0_NDVI": "float"}, ["d_0_NDVI"]);
}
///////////////*******************************//////////////////////
/////////////The function to interpolate EVI
function EVIinterpolator(img){
  img=ee.Image(img)
  // get the first day of the subsample 
  var begin = ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'));
  // get the end day of the subsample
  //var end = begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta));
  var difference = ee.String(ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'))).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).slice(5).compareTo("12-18").neq(0)
                   .and(ee.String(ee.Date(ee.Number(img.get('system:time_start'))).format('YYYY-MM-dd')).slice(5).compareTo("12-19").neq(0))
  var end = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
            begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta)),
            begin.add(ee.Number(timeDelta1))
  )
  //convert to an image
  var minDD = ee.Image(filledDate.filterDate(begin).first()); 
  var maxDD = ee.Image(filledDate.filterDate(end).first());
  
  //calculate the coefficent
  var angularCoeff = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
                     (maxDD.select('d_0_EVI').subtract(minDD.select('d_0_EVI'))).divide(timeDelta),
                     (maxDD.select('d_0_EVI').subtract(minDD.select('d_0_EVI'))).divide(timeDelta1)
  )
  var q = ee.Algorithms.If(difference,
          ((maxDD.select('time').multiply(minDD.select('d_0_EVI'))).subtract(minDD.select('time').multiply(maxDD.select('d_0_EVI'))))
          .divide(timeDelta),
          ((maxDD.select('time').multiply(minDD.select('d_0_EVI'))).subtract(minDD.select('time').multiply(maxDD.select('d_0_EVI'))))
          .divide(timeDelta1)
  )
  //refilter the out collection
  var mnth = filledDate.filterDate(begin,end);
  
  // interpolate the values
  function ndviInterpolator(img){
    var NDVI = (img.select('time').multiply(angularCoeff)).add(q);
    var result = img.select('d_0_EVI').unmask(NDVI);
    return result;
  }
  var filledMth = mnth.map(ndviInterpolator);
  return filledMth.cast({"d_0_EVI": "float"}, ["d_0_EVI"]);
}
///////////////*******************************//////////////////////
//apply the interpolation function to NDVI
var sgliNDVICollection =  ee.ImageCollection(imgCll.map(NDVIinterpolator).flatten().toList(3000)).map(function(img){
  //.divide(10000) why the "system: time_Start" disappear after divide?
  return img.clip(EuropeBoundary)//.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000);
});

var NDVI=sgliNDVICollection;
print("NDVI",NDVI)
Map.addLayer(NDVI,{},"NDVI")

//apply the interpolation function to NDVI
var sgliEVICollection =  ee.ImageCollection(imgCll.map(EVIinterpolator).flatten().toList(3000)).map(function(img){
  return img.clip(EuropeBoundary)//.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000);
});
var EVI=sgliEVICollection;
print("EVI",EVI)
Map.addLayer(EVI,{},"EVI")
/////////////////////////**********************************


//*******API************
//1979-01-02T00:00:00 - 2020-07-09T00:00:00
///////filter ERA5 collection according to Date
//because t=34, so we need to use 34 days data before 2018-01-01
//And drop them after API calculation
var firstDayPreci = ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear).subtract(1)).cat('-11-28');
var firstDay = ee.String(firstYear.toString()).cat('-01-01');
var lastDay  = ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear).add(1)).cat('-01-01');
var lastDayExtra1  = ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear).add(1)).cat('-01-02');
var ERA5LandPre = ERA5Land.filterDate(firstDayPreci,lastDayExtra1).map(function(img){
                    return img.select(["total_precipitation",'total_evaporation']).clip(EuropeBoundary)
                          // 20151129T00 represents total precipitation of 20151128 (T01-T00), so one hour shift earlier
                           .set("system:time_start",ee.Number(img.get("system:time_start")).subtract(86400000))
                  })
           .filterDate(firstDayPreci,lastDay)
           .filterMetadata("hour","equals",00)
print("ERA5LandPre",ERA5LandPre)
print("ERA5LandPresize",ERA5LandPre.size())
Map.addLayer(ERA5LandPre,{min:0,max:0.05},'ERA5LandPre')
ERA5LandPre = ERA5LandPre.map(function(img){
  return img.select("total_precipitation").add(img.select('total_evaporation'))
         .set("system:time_start",ee.Number(img.get("system:time_start")))
         .set('hour',img.get('hour'))
})
//t=34(0-33) k=0.91 
var lagRange = 33;
// Looks for all images up to 'lagRange' days away from the current image.
var maxDiffFilter = ee.Filter([
  ee.Filter.maxDifference({
    difference: lagRange * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })]);

//Images before, sorted in ascending order (so closest is last).
//here we cannot remove the equals, otherwise the timeseries will lost first element
var FilterBefore = ee.Filter.and(maxDiffFilter, ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('system:time_start', null, 'system:time_start'))
var ERA5LandPre_BeforeJoinedCols = ee.Join.saveAll('before', 'system:time_start', true).apply(ERA5LandPre, ERA5LandPre, FilterBefore)
print('ERA5LandPre_BeforeJoinedCols',ERA5LandPre_BeforeJoinedCols);

////////////calculate apiCollection over all precipitation datasets
var apiLandCollection = ERA5LandPre_BeforeJoinedCols.map(function(image1) {
  image1 = ee.Image(image1);
  var beforeImages=ee.List(image1.get('before'))
  beforeImages=beforeImages.map(function(image2){
  image2=ee.Image(image2)
  var startTime=ee.Number(image1.get('system:time_start'))
  var id=startTime.subtract(ee.Number(image2.get('system:time_start'))).divide(86400000);
  return ee.Image(image2).set('id',id)
})
  beforeImages=ee.ImageCollection(beforeImages)//.filterMetadata("id","not_equals",0)
  var k=ee.Image(0.91)
  var apiItem=beforeImages.map(function(image3){
    image3=ee.Image(image3)
    var id=ee.Image(ee.Number(image3.get('id')));
    var api=image3.multiply(k.pow(id))
    return api
  })
  var api=ee.ImageCollection(apiItem).sum()
  return api.rename([ee.String('band').cat(ee.String('_')).cat(image1.get('system:index')).cat("_APEI")])
            .set('system:index1',ee.String(image1.get('system:index')).slice(0,8))
            .set("system:time_start",image1.get("system:time_start"))
})
print('APILand',apiLandCollection);
apiLandCollection=ee.ImageCollection(apiLandCollection
                  .filterMetadata("system:index","not_less_than",ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear)).cat("0102T00")))
print('APILand',apiLandCollection);
var APILand = apiLandCollection
Map.addLayer(APILand.toBands(),{min:0,max:0.04},"APILand")
/////////////////////*****************************
//air temperature
var preImgCol = ERA5Land.filterDate(firstDay.cat("T01"),lastDay.cat("T01")).select("temperature_2m").map(function(col){
  //0102T00(equals to 0101T24) -> 0101T23
  //0101T01+0101T02+...+0102T00(equals to 0101T24)
  var system_time_start = ee.Number(col.get('system:time_start')).subtract(3600000)
  var system_time_end = ee.Number(col.get('system:time_end')).subtract(3600000)
  var date=ee.Date(ee.Number(col.get('system:time_start')).subtract(3600000)).format("YYYY-MM-dd")
  var preImgCol=col.set('date',date).set('system:time_start',system_time_start).set('system:time_end',system_time_end);
  return preImgCol
})
print(preImgCol.size())
print("preImgCol Tair",ee.ImageCollection(preImgCol.toList(8784).slice(8000,8784)))
// //merge data from hourly into daily with join function
var join = ee.Join.saveAll("matches");
var filter = ee.Filter.equals({ 
  leftField: "date", 
  rightField: "date" 
}); 
var joinImgs = join.apply(preImgCol.filterMetadata("hour","equals",1), preImgCol, filter); 
print("joinImgs",joinImgs.first())
var TairCollection = joinImgs.map(function(image) { 
  var _imgList = ee.List(image.get("matches")); 
  var _tempCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(_imgList); 
  //due to it is hourly, so we need to calculate the average of everyday
  //Temperature measured in kelvin can be converted to degrees Celsius (°C) by subtracting 273.15.
  var _dayImg = _tempCol.mean().subtract(273.15); 
  var _date = image.get("date"); 
  _dayImg = _dayImg.set("system:time_start", ee.Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd", _date).millis())
                  .set('date',_date)
  return _dayImg.rename("Tair")//.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000); 
}); 
TairCollection = ee.ImageCollection(TairCollection)
print("TairCollection",TairCollection)
Map.addLayer(ee.ImageCollection(TairCollection),{min:0,max:0.05},'TairCollection')
////evaporation
var evapoCollection = ERA5Land.filterDate(firstDay,lastDayExtra1)
                .map(function(img){
                  //var date = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).format("YYYY-MM-dd")
                  return img.select("total_evaporation").rename("Evapo")//.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000)
                            .set("system:time_start",ee.Number(img.get("system:time_start")).subtract(86400000))
                          //.set("date",date)
                })
                .filterDate(firstDay,lastDay).filterMetadata("hour","equals",00)
print("evapoCollection",evapoCollection)
//////////////////////////*************************************

///////////////////////////***********************************
//LST
var LST=ee.ImageCollection("users/qianrswaterAmerica/LSTEuropeMOD11A1")
var dayLSTfilter = ee.String("MODIS_LST_Blended_Day_Europe").cat(ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear)))
var nightLSTfilter = ee.String("MODIS_LST_Blended_Night_Europe").cat(ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear)))
var dayLST = LST.filterMetadata("system:index","equals",dayLSTfilter).first().divide(100);
var nightLST = LST.filterMetadata("system:index","equals",nightLSTfilter).first().divide(100);
print("dayLST",dayLST)
print("nightLST",nightLST)
function batchRename_dailyLST(image){
  var rename=image.bandNames().map(function(name){
    return ee.String("band_").cat(ee.String(name).slice(-10)).cat(ee.String("_dailyLST"));
  })
  return image.rename(rename);
}
var dailyLST0=batchRename_dailyLST(dayLST.add(nightLST).divide(ee.Number(2)))
.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000);
print("dailyLST0",dailyLST0)
function batchRename_dailyLSTDiff(image){
  var rename=image.bandNames().map(function(name){
    return ee.String("band_").cat(ee.String(name).slice(-10)).cat(ee.String("_dailyLSTDiff"));
  })
  return image.rename(rename);
}
var dailyLSTDiff0=batchRename_dailyLSTDiff(dayLST.subtract(nightLST))
.reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000);
print("dailyLSTDiff0",dailyLSTDiff0)

///dailyLST
var bandNamesdailyLST=dailyLST0.bandNames();
var dailyLST=ee.ImageCollection(bandNamesdailyLST.map(function(BandNameElement){
  var stringLength=ee.String(BandNameElement).length();
  var stryearBegin=ee.String(BandNameElement).slice(-19,-9)
  var startIndex=ee.String(BandNameElement).rindex(stryearBegin)
  var DateString=ee.String(BandNameElement).slice(startIndex,startIndex.add(10))
  var yearStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(0,4));
  var monthStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(5,7));
  var DayStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(8,10));
   
  return ee.Image(dailyLST0.select([BandNameElement])).rename(['dailyLST']).cast({"dailyLST": "double"}, ["dailyLST"])
.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(yearStr.int(), monthStr.int(), DayStr.int()).millis())
.set('bandName',BandNameElement)
.set("system:index",stryearBegin)
}))
print("dailyLST",dailyLST)
Map.addLayer(dailyLST,{},"dailyLST")
////dailyLSTDiff
var bandNamesdailyLSTDiff=dailyLSTDiff0.bandNames();
var dailyLSTDiff=ee.ImageCollection(bandNamesdailyLSTDiff.map(function(BandNameElement){
  var stringLength=ee.String(BandNameElement).length();
  var stryearBegin=ee.String(BandNameElement).slice(-23,-13)
  var startIndex=ee.String(BandNameElement).rindex(stryearBegin)
  var DateString=ee.String(BandNameElement).slice(startIndex,startIndex.add(10))
  var yearStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(0,4));
  var monthStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(5,7));
  var DayStr=ee.Number.parse(DateString.slice(8,10));
   
  return ee.Image(dailyLSTDiff0.select([BandNameElement])).rename(['dailyLSTDiff']).cast({"dailyLSTDiff": "double"}, ["dailyLSTDiff"])
.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(yearStr.int(), monthStr.int(), DayStr.int()).millis())
.set('bandName',BandNameElement)
.set("system:index",stryearBegin)
}))
print("dailyLSTDiff",dailyLSTDiff)
Map.addLayer(dailyLSTDiff,{},"dailyLSTDiff")
////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////
var modis = MOD13A2.first().reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000)
// Get information about the MODIS projection.
var modisProjection = modis.projection();
print('MODIS projection:', modisProjection);

//soilTexture
//print(ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/clay_mean").projection().nominalScale())
// divide 10, convert "g/kg" to "g/100g (%)"
var clayFraction =ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/clay_mean").select("clay_0-5cm_mean")
                  .rename("clay").divide(10).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250)
var sandFraction =ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/sand_mean").select("sand_0-5cm_mean")
                  .rename("sand").divide(10).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250)
var siltFraction =ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/silt_mean").select("silt_0-5cm_mean")
                  .rename("silt").divide(10).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250)
//porosity
//divide 100, convert "cg/cm³" to "kg/dm³", which is same as "g/cm³"
var bulkDensity=ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/bdod_mean").select("bdod_0-5cm_mean")
                .divide(100).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250)
var porosity = ee.Image(1).subtract(bulkDensity.divide(ee.Image(2.65)))
              .rename("porosity").reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250)
//organic matter content
var soc = ee.Image("projects/soilgrids-isric/soc_mean");
//divide 10, convert "dg/kg" to "g/kg", then divide 10, convert "g/kg" to "%"
var omc = soc.select("soc_0-5cm_mean").multiply(0.01).multiply(1.724).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,250).rename("omc")

var soilProper = clayFraction.addBands(sandFraction).addBands(siltFraction).addBands(porosity).addBands(omc)
Map.addLayer(soilProper,{min:0,max:100},"soilProper250")
var resample = function(image) {
  return image.resample('bilinear')
              .reproject({
                    crs: modisProjection,
                    scale: 1000})
};
soilProper = resample(soilProper)
Map.addLayer(soilProper,{min:0,max:100},"soilProper1000")
////////////////////////
var longitude = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select("longitude").reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000).rename("lon")
//Map.addLayer(longitude,{},"longitude")
var latitude = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select("latitude").reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000).rename("lat")
//Map.addLayer(latitude,{},"latitude")
var elevation=TIele.select("elevation").reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000)
var TI=TIele.select("TI").reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000)

////////////////////////combine all predictors
var predictors=dailyLST.map(function(img){
  var time=img.get("system:time_start")
  var dailyLSTDiff1=dailyLSTDiff.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("LST_Diff")
  var NDVI1=NDVI.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("NDVI_SG_linear").divide(10000)
  var EVI1=EVI.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("EVI_SG_linear").divide(10000)
  var Preci1=ERA5LandPre.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("Preci").multiply(1000)
  var APILand1=APILand.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("apei").multiply(1000)
  var Tair1 = TairCollection.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("Tair")
  var Evapo1 = evapoCollection.filterMetadata("system:time_start","equals",time).first().rename("Evapo").multiply(-1000)
  return img.rename("LST_DAILY").addBands(dailyLSTDiff1)
            .addBands(Preci1).addBands(APILand1)
            .addBands(Tair1).addBands(Evapo1)
            .addBands(NDVI1).addBands(EVI1).addBands(TI)
            .addBands(soilProper.select("porosity")).addBands(soilProper.select("omc"))
            .addBands(soilProper.select("clay")).addBands(soilProper.select("sand")).addBands(soilProper.select("silt"))
            .addBands(longitude).addBands(latitude).addBands(elevation)
            .addBands(WTD)
            .addBands(DTB)
})
.map(function(img){
  return img.clip(EuropeBoundary).reproject("EPSG:4326",null,1000)
})
print("predictors",predictors.first())
Map.addLayer(predictors.first(),{},"predictors",false)

////////////
print("/////   training /////////////////////")
Map.addLayer(trainTest,{},'trainTest',false)

print(trainTest.first())
/////////select a certain number of training and testing samples
var sample=trainTest;
var station=sample.toList(556443).map(function(a){
  return ee.Feature(a).get('station')
})

sample=sample.randomColumn();
var sampleSplit = 0.5; 
sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', sampleSplit));
print('sampleFirst',sample.first())
print('sampleSize',sample.size())
//Map.addLayer(sample,{},'samples')
var station=sample.toList(556443).map(function(a){
  return ee.Feature(a).get('station')
})
print("station size",station.distinct())
NLsamples = NLsamples.randomColumn();
var trainingNL = NLsamples.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.75));
var testingNL = NLsamples.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', 0.75));
print("trainingNL",trainingNL)
print("testingNL",testingNL)
sample = sample.merge(trainingNL)
print('sampleSize',sample.size())
// //////////split training and testing samples
sample = sample.randomColumn();
print('sampleSize',sample.size())
var split = 0.75;  // Roughly 75% training, 25% testing.
var training = sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
print('trainingSize',training.size())
var testing = sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
//print('testingSize',testing.size())
// Make a Random Forest classifier and train it
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({
  numberOfTrees:20,
  minLeafPopulation:1, 
  bagFraction:0.5,
  seed:0
}).setOutputMode('REGRESSION')
    .train({
      features: training,
      classProperty: 'soil moisture',
      inputProperties: [
                      "apei",
                      //"Preci",
                      'Tair','Evapo',
                      'LST_DAILY','LST_Diff',
                      'EVI_SG_linear','NDVI_SG_linear',
                      'clay','sand','silt',
                      'TI','elevation',
                      "lat","lon",
                      'porosity',
                      "omc"
                      ,'WTD'
                      ,'DTB'
                      ]
    });
//calculate the importance of every land surface feature
var importance=classifier.explain();
print('importance',importance)
var SM=ee.ImageCollection(predictors.toList(366).slice(0,366)).map(function(img){
  return img.classify(classifier).multiply(1000).round().toUint16()
})
print("SM",SM.size())
//print("spatial resolution of SM",SM.first().projection().nominalScale().getInfo())
function batchRename(image){
  var rename=image.bandNames().map(function(name){
    return ee.String("band_").cat(ee.String(name));
  })
  return image.rename(rename);
}
SM=batchRename(SM.toBands())

Export.image.toAsset({
          image: SM,
          description:ee.String("SM").cat(ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear))).cat("Europe1km").getInfo(),
          scale: 1000,
          region: EuropeBoundary,
          crs:"EPSG:4326",
          assetId:ee.String("GlobalSSM1km0509/SM").cat(ee.String(ee.Number(firstYear))).cat("Europe1km").getInfo(),
          maxPixels: 1e13,
          pyramidingPolicy: {'.default': 'sample'}
      });
Map.addLayer(EuropeBoundary,{},"EuropeBoundary")
```